# The type or namespace name GridViewHelper could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

Fist off, I'm very new to ASP.NET and Visual Web Developer Express.

I have a datagrid that I want to display subtotals in and have grouping.

I found this http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm which looks great. I've added the classes files to my projects App_code folder and re-built the project.

But when I try and use the GridViewHelper I get the error "The type or namespace name GridViewHelper could not be found"

Tried adding using GridViewHelper; to the top of my page but that also gets underlined and the same error.

So how do I tell my project to use the classes I've added?? I think this is a really stupid question but I cant find an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: [App_Code folder is missing in VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277742/app-code-folder-is-missing-in-vs-2010)

> So, for Web App Projects, you should instead Add a folder called something like 'CodeFolder' and then add you class in there. Then right click properties on that class file and set its build config to **compile rather than content**.

It's now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the source code from the link you provided, I believe the reason you can't add it is because it is not an actual namespace.

However, in the app_code, they provided a GridViewHelper.cs, just make sure it's in your own app_code file and it should work.

Comment: I've added all files from the downloaded App_Code folder to an App_Code folder I added to my solution. But this didn't help.
Also tried adding the same namespace to the GridViewHelper file. But it didn't help.