# ASP.NET App Code folder

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

If an ASP.NET application contains classes then there are two options: 1) put the classes in the appcode folder or 2) Create a separate class library.

I have found many web pages that discuss the benefits of option 2 and I was already aware of these benefits e.g.

1) The Business Logic layer is separated from the presentation layer
2) Code can be shared between multiple client applications e.g. an ASP.NET website and a VB.NET application client.

I cannot find any web pages that discuss the benefits of option 1.

My question is: are there any benefits to option 1? Am I over thinking this?

Comment: if you have just couple of classes, why not use option 1?

Comment: @Alex, thanks.  There are about 60 classes in total.  I am trying to understand the benefits of option 1 over option 2.

Comment: if you have web application (not web site) then use option 2.

Comment: see similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277742/app-code-folder-is-missing-in-vs-2010

Comment: so, I think benefits of option 1: it's simplicity, perfect for simple sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any benefits to using App_Code?

It's a bit subjective, but in general, Web Application Projects scale much better than Web Site Projects.

As far as I know, the only *benefit* of Web Site Projects is that you can change App_Code files with out having to recompile them. But many (myself included) don't like that because it makes it possible to change code on a live web server, which is almost always a bad idea.

> App_Code or separate class library?

It depends. If you need to use these classes in multiple projects, create a separate class library. If you only need it in this particular web site, App_Code is perfectly acceptable.

See [Web Site or Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application) and [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but this has confused me even more (sorry).  I have a website project and use the "publish website" option to deploy the compiled code to the server.  Is this actually a web application?

Comment: which VS you use? When you choose File -> New, you can select Web Site or project. If you have Web Site you can convert to web application.

Comment: The website was developed by someone else.  It is a website because there is no project file.

Comment: you can use library for web site too

Comment: Are there any limitations using a DLL with a website instead of an application?

Comment: If you have no `.csproj`, it is a Web Site project. You can reference .NET dlls in both project types.

Comment: Thanks before I mark this - are there any limitations to using a DLL with a website? I have read your link.

Comment: There are no limitations that I'm aware of. The limiting factors of Web Site Projects are more about project structure, not its references.

Comment: Would you convert it to an app if you were including a DLL?

Comment: No, adding a reference to a dll works just fine in web sites.

Comment: Just one more thing (for an upvote).  Which option would you choose?(see question)

Comment: I guess my answer was a bit vague, sorry about that. Does my update makes things more clear?

Comment: I don't understand why your talking about websites and we apps as both can have class libraries.

Comment: I felt it was relevant since you asked about App_Code. Feel free to ignore that part.

Comment: No, App_Code is only used in Web Site projects.

Comment: If you use a web app then you have to produce a dl if you want to use classesl? (last question I promise)

Comment: Nope, classes can be in any folder in a web application project.