# VS 2010 App_folder Is missing from Add ASP.NET Folder & App_Code Namespace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, namespaces, asp.net-4.0, app-code

I could not add App_Code For my project, so I decided to add It as new Folder an naming it "App_code".

Is this is correct way to add this folder to my Project?

If this is correct way , why I can not find the namespace "MyProjectName.App_Code" in code behind although I defined the namespace in code behind of each Page as "using MyProjectName.App_Code;"

Comment: possible duplicate of [App\_Code folder is missing in VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277742/app-code-folder-is-missing-in-vs-2010)

Answer (score 0):

Add new Folder to your Application And Name it As "App_Cpde".

Add new Class To the App_Code Folder From Add->Class and Change the its Property "Build Action" from content To compile.

best regards